# Creating a Interactive, Walkthrough in Blender

Tags: camera

I can already make my home designs in blender, but I want to be able to walk through my house like you do in a game. I want it to feel like it is really my current living room in the real world.  All I can do now is lay a camera track and move along that track. Should I only create the house in blender, and import it into Twinmotion, or should I use a different application?

Comment: Suggestion: Game engine

Comment: Hi Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that users can at a glance understand what your post is about. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid anything not strictly essential to the post. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and makes your question findable for future users. See ["*What is the problem with posting an image or link and asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: You could either:
1. Create the rooms, furniture, etc. in Blender and then export it to Unreal Engine or Unity

2. Design everything in Unreal Engine or Unity

(I'd stick with those two for this type of thing.)